# In python, how to check two object have the same attribute values when the objects could possible be None?

Tags: python

I have two objects and I want to check if they have the same attribute values. But the objects could be None. I have the following code. Other than that, could it be simpler to do the same job?

```
    if obj1 is None and obj2 is None:
        return True

    if obj1 is None and obj2 is not None:
        return False

    if obj1 is not None and obj2 is None:
        return False

    if obj1.val != obj2.val:
        return False
```

Comment: I guess, you are missing `if obj1.val == obj2.val: return True`?

Comment: if obj1.val == obj2.val, then it will pass the test and go on with other operations. It is not a miss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole thing boils down to:

```
if obj1 is None or obj2 is None:
    return obj1 is obj2 # we know at least one is None; are they both None?

return obj1.val == obj2.val # both are definitely not None, compare vals
```

Test it:

```py
>>> def eq(a, b): return a is b if a is None or b is None else a.val == b.val
... 
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Node = namedtuple("Node", "val")
>>> eq(Node(1), Node(1))
True
>>> eq(Node(1), Node(2))
False
>>> eq(Node(2), None)
False
>>> eq(None, None)
True
>>> eq(None, Node(1))
False
```

As a practical application, this can be used as part of a recursive algorithm in determining whether two binary trees are the same, as in [Leetcode: Same Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/). This might explain why your last condition, the `obj1.val == obj2.val` case, is missing, because that's your recursive case.

Comment: I would maybe make `obj1 == obj2` -> `obj1 is obj2` to signal even more that we expect *both to be `None`*

Comment: That's exactly what this code snippet is used for, checking all nodes in two trees are the same. I just felt the comparison is too tedious. Maybe I should put the comparison into a utility function.

Answer (score 1):

For the middle two comparisons,

```
if obj1 is None and obj2 is not None:
    return False

if obj1 is not None and obj2 is None:
    return False
```

can be reduced to

```
if (obj1 is None) != (obj2 is None):
    return False
```

In other words, establish two boolean values representing none-ness, and then compare those values to each other.

Comment: basically XOR, I think

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, and you can easily accomplish the same thing using the `^` operator but it's less legible.

Comment: it is a little bit hard to understand this code.